# Search for Calendar Items by body contents

Tags: office365, exchange-server, powershell-5.0

A customer accidentally merged her calendar with another and has these events that she doesn't need that are constantly conflicting with her actual meetings and there are enough of these items to be a problem
So we were looking for an easy way to delete them all but just the ones that she doesn't need
They all have this hyper link in the body of it
https://app.asana.com/
But all of the subjects are unique
Here was my attempt

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Search-Mailbox -identity user@domain.com -TargetMailbox results@domain.com - 
SearchQuery "https://app.asana.com/"

cmdlet Search-Mailbox at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
TargetFolder: results
WARNING: Search-Mailbox is being deprecated. Please use New-ComplianceSearch and related eDiscovery 
commands instead.
WARNING: The Search-Mailbox cmdlet returns up to 10000 results per mailbox if a search query is 
specified. To return
more than 10000 results, use the New-MailboxSearch cmdlet or the In-Place eDiscovery & Hold console 
in the Exchange
Administration Center.
The property keyword isn't supported.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParserException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=MN2PR10MB4014,RequestId=ab8cd083-d91f-44c2-a79d- 
8b02aa741bd4,TimeStamp=10/23/201
9 3:07:32 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ParserException] 8EBF7B47
+ PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

The only thing i can find on google revolves around this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/search-mailbox?view=exchange-ps
but nothing about actually pulling contents from the body.
Microsoft support was stumped as they are under the impression we should be able to but they do not know how to. That was from the agent on the phone and his tier 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within outlook you can filter by anything which allows you to search for the events. They all had the hyper link so i just ctrl + a and deleted all of them.